# how to do pivotaltracker oauth authentication using curl

Tags: php, curl

I am new to `curl`. I'm trying basic authentication using curl with pivotal tracker

```
error:{"error":"Needs authentication credentials.","possible_fix":"Try basic auth, or include header X-TrackerToken.","code":"unauthenticated","kind":"error".
```

1. here is simple code i used to authenticate:

   ```
    $ch = curl_init();
   $data = array('$token'=>'858e234da*****');
   // set URL and other appropriate options
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.pivotaltracker.com/services/v5/me");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
   // grab URL and pass it to the browser

    $response =curl_exec($ch);
    var_dump($response);
    // close cURL resource, and free up system resources
     curl_close($ch);
   ```
2. how to authenticate my application with  token as pivotal tracker support simple ouath authentication.
3. i would like to  explain  steps of authentication

   a.)user enter user name  and password.

   b.)then enter token of your profile.

   c.) now page is redirected your dashboard.

Comment: Seems to me you are using the token the wrong way.

Comment: thanks sr i would take care about these errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Try basic auth, or include header X-TrackerToken.

Which seems to me is asking you to submit the token as a `X-TrackerToken` header.

You can try something like this, though I can't find the *pivotaltracker* documentation.

```
$ch = curl_init('https://www.pivotaltracker.com/services/v5/me'); 
// or just remove the customrequest too
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');                                                                                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'X-TrackerToken: 858e234da*****'                                                                      
);                                                                                                                   

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

---

**update**

Found the [documentation](http://www.pivotaltracker.com/help/api/rest/edge).

It shows something like:

```
export TOKEN='your Pivotal Tracker API token'
curl -X GET -H "X-TrackerToken: $TOKEN" "https://www.pivotaltracker.com/services/edge/stories/558"
```

Comment: i recived error: Notice: Undefined variable: data_string

Comment: now i recived error:{ "code": "http_method_not_supported", "possible_fix": "This endpoint only supports these http methods: GET", "error": "You tried to access this resource with an HTTP method that is not supported", "kind": "error" }

Comment: i have tried like this $data = array('$token'=>'858e234******');

Comment: @user3306026 change the curl request to GET?

Comment: again i same issue :{ "kind": "error", "code": "http_method_not_supported", "error": "You tried to access this resource with an HTTP method that is not supported", "possible_fix": "This endpoint only supports these http methods: GET" }